# How to stop Jira/Xray from updating my test case name/summary?

Tags: robotframework, jira, jira-xray

I am using POST /api/v2/import/execution/robot to import my Robot Framework test results to Jira/Xray. I use robot tags to identify which Xray test executions I want to update. Problem is, that in robot file I want the test case name to be "Example" and in Xray I want the name to be "Real deal". When I POST my test executions to Jira, it automatically updates the tickets summary as follows:

XXX updated the Summary 30 minutes ago
Real deal -> Example.

So the ticket name changed, and I don't want that.

How can I stop this from happening?

Read through the documentation and tried to google, but can't find anything related.

Comment: Hi @tubi, if my answer helped you out, can you please mark it as correct? Appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, and to clarify, you're using Xray on Jira Cloud.
Currently, the behaviour is non-configurable. For the time being, the only solution would be to change "Example" to "Real deal"; I would avoid having different names in RF side and on Jira side.
Finally, my other recommendation would be to reach out to [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) asking for an improvement, so that the team can analyze your need.